# How to access array computer by a function within Codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, function, templates

I have a function as follow:

```
function get_employee_information() 
{
$this->db
        ->select('id, name');
$query = $this->db->get('sales_people');

$employee_names = array();
$employee_ids = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $employee_names[$row->id] = $row->name;
    $employee_ids[] = $row->id;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access this data from within an output to template, like this:

```
$this->get_employee_information();    
$output = $this->template->write_view('main', 'records', array(
            'employee_names' => $employee_names,
            'employee_ids' => $employee_ids,
            ), false);
```

Yet this isn't displaying anything. I feel like this is something small and I should know better. When I tun print_r($arrayname) on either array WITHIN the function, I get the suspected array values. When I print_r OUTSIDE of the function, it returns nothing.

Comment: your function is not returning anything.. Add `return     array('employee_names'=>$employee_names, 'employee_ids'=>$employee_ids);` at the end of your funtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything. Add the return shown below.

```
function get_employee_information() 
{
    $this->db->select('id, name');
    $query = $this->db->get('sales_people');

    $employee_names = array();
    $employee_ids = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $employee_names[$row->id] = $row->name;
        $employee_ids[] = $row->id;
     }

    return array(
        'employee_names'=>$employee_names, 
        'employee_ids'=>$employee_ids,
     ); 
}
```

You are not setting the `return` value of the function to a variable

```
$employee_info = $this->get_employee_information();    
$output = 
    $this->template->write_view(
        'main', 'records', 
        array(
            'employee_names' => $employee_info['employee_names'],
            'employee_ids' => $employee_info['employee_ids'],
         ), 
         false
     );
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I had tried return $employee_names; and return $employee_ids; but not having them return as an array. I see. Thank you!